# Angular HttpClient "Unknown Error" with service worker and long-running request

Tags: angular, google-chrome, service-worker, angular-httpclient, angular-service-worker

I make an HTTP call using the Angular HttpClient. The request takes ca. 8 minutes to complete and works fine without service worker.
But when activating the Angular service worker, the request is canceled after 5 minutes with the following error object:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: 'Unknown Error', url: 'https://app.dbal.dbmc.comp.db.de/frequent/platformservice/10518/lezel/commands/shipmentImport', ok: false, …}
error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: 'error', …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for https://app.dbal.dbmc.comp.db.de/frequent/platformservice/10518/lezel/commands/shipmentImport: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "https://app.dbal.dbmc.comp.db.de/frequent/platformservice/10518/lezel/commands/shipmentImport"
```

In the Chrome network panel, I see two requests, one targeting the service worker (the one which is canceled) and a second one executed by the service worker (this one is not canceled, it has an HTTP 401 error, but that's expected):
[image: Network Panel]

I wonder if there is some implicit timeout of 5 minutes concerning HTTP requests done with service workers.
Does anyone know how to increase that timeout or what else could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to bypass the service worker by adding a special header in an HttpInterceptor:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
  const newRequest = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.append('ngsw-bypass', 'true') });
  return next.handle(newRequest);
}
```